# How to use Codepush with App center in React-native

Tags: react-native, continuous-deployment, visual-studio-app-center, code-push

I started to use Microsoft App center to improve my CI/CD process developing my react-native app, but I can't understand how the update flow works together with codepush.

I configured 3 branches

- dev
- staging
- release

The current Flow:
I merge a new feature in dev and test it locally, after that I move dev to staging where an app center build is triggered to release an iOS / Android test version.
If that is successful, I merge it to release where automatically a new release version is built and pushed to both app stores.

Now I integrated code push to deliver over-the-air updates, but I can't figure out where to put the changes.

For example, if I do some small changes I do not need to test, for normal I would do that in dev, merge it to release, and deploy a new version to the app store after.
If I want to do it via code push I can do it via the app center CLI, but in which branch should I keep the changes?

If I merge it to release, it would automatically trigger the build process, deploying the new app to the stores, but if I keep it in the other branch release and the other branch will diverge over time.

I think I miss something in the update flow, would be nice if someone gives me an explanation

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but generally speaking features should not be merged into dev until they have been tested thoroughly - `dev` or `development` branch should be stable (i.e. no/as few as possible bugs and untested features)

Comment: Codepush is only for hot fixes not for over the air updates, you can do it but not preferred because you says v1 in configs and update the JS part to v1.1, in terms on branch this should be a patch branch which you send the codepush manually